# Send/Receive requests. Android <> Server

Tags: android

I would like my application to send/receive requests from a LOCAL server, my laptop for instance. Can anyone provide me with the necessary steps I need to follow in order to understand how this can work with an Android application?

Here is an example. Let's assume my application wants to compute "1+1" however it doesn't know whether or not 1+1 is equal to 2. The only way to get around this issue is to send a request which is basically the algebraic expression(1+1) and the answer(equal to 2) to the server which will check the answer from a file that it has to read and send back to the application a message stating whether or not the answer is correct.

Comment: Your question is overly broad for this forum. Btw, there is no difference between a local server and a normal web server. As long as it's remote and uses tcp/ip, there is no real difference. So your question is just how to build an android app with a backend, a vast question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using [Android Query](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/) to make http get/post requests and it works pretty good:

```
String url = "http://10.0.2.2/add/1/1";        
aq.ajax(url, JSONObject.class, new AjaxCallback() {

  @Override
  public void callback(String url, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status) {

    if(json != null){                              
      //successful ajax call, show status code and json content
      Toast.makeText(aq.getContext(), "result: " + json.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                    
    }else{                             
      //ajax error, show error code
      Toast.makeText(aq.getContext(), "Error:" + status.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
  }
});
```

You can also chose [html/xml/byte](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/wiki/AsyncAPI#HTML/XML) as response type.

Comment: Alright thanks I will see what I can do with it. Help appreciated.

Comment: @Batzi you can show your appreciation by marking it as the answer if it resolved your question.